# Conditional Formatting Formula to highlight all matching values found in another table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am looking to use conditional formatting to highlight all values in the table that are found in another table. I am new to formulas for conditional formatting so please forgive my ignorance.

So

```
Table A                              Table B

*10 x 2*                             13 x 26
8 x 6                                20 x 20
*4 x 9*                              18 x 6
3 x 1                                40 x 1
18 x 2                               10 x 2
*6 x 6*                              4 x 9
*13 x 26*                            10 x 15
79 x 2                               6 x 6
```

So the formula will be conditional formatting for Table A, searching Table B for any matching values and highlight them in table A. In the above example * * serves as highlighting.

I have tried using countif/s but that is very clearly the wrong direction for conditional formatting. Other solutions I have found are only searching for specific words or phrases not searching all data in tables and matching.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `MATCH()` function

Comment: ```=MATCH(Table393[XX],Table393402410[XX],0)``` - This formula when used in Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Cell Rules -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format.             This yields a problem with the formula. It works to give me a match number when used in a regular cell but does not work in conditional formatting. Is there something I need to add to make it work in that use case?

Comment: You cannot use `Structured References` in conditional formatting in that way. Name the `Table B` as `CheckList` and use it in conditional formatting

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, are you able to provide an example formula?

Comment: I have posted an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a quick example:

[image]

---

- Define Name the `Table B` as `CheckList`
- Select the `Table A` and Hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
- On doing above opens the `New Formatting Rule` Window
- Select the last rule - `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
- Enter the following formula

---

```
=MATCH(A2,CheckList,0)
```

---

- Click on format and use specific formatting as per your preference
- Click OK Twice.

---

Comment: When I try this I am still getting the "There's a problem with this formula." Dialogue Box, does this only work in newer versions of excel? I'm in 2016

Comment: The method shown works from `Excel 2010+` onwards, Just tried with `Excel 2010` , `Excel 2013` , `Excel 2016` , `Excel 2019` `Excel 2021` and everytime it seemed to work, now say and show

Comment: This is extremely strange, I have followed your instructions exactly and I am always getting that error. I tried a new sheet, a new workbook. Nothing works.

Comment: @BCOR what formula you have used, show a screenshot

Comment: edited post to add screenshots

Comment: `CheckList` is only one column and not two.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256012/discussion-between-bcor-and-mayukh-bhattacharya).